# TeXstudio scripting with system call and "?"

Tags: texstudio, scripts

I want to make a simple script in texstudio, which i can use to search a selected word in my browser.

Everything works quite right, except i can't call the query command correctly.

The "?" seems to be a cut off. But replacing, urlencoding, whatever does not do the trick either.

How can i encode the "?" in the URL or is there a flag i could try?

I tried system() and buildManager.runCommand(), both do the same in this case.

```
%SCRIPT
u=encodeURI("https://ecosia.org/search?q="+cursor.selectedText())
//u=encodeURI("https://ecosia.org/search\?q="+cursor.selectedText())
//u="https://ecosia.org/search\\%3Fq="+cursor.selectedText()
//u="https://ecosia.org/search%3Fq="+cursor.selectedText()
//u="https://ecosia.org/search?q="+cursor.selectedText()
//u="https://ecosia.org/search\?q="+cursor.selectedText()
//buildManager.runCommand("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe\" \""+u+"\"")
system("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe\" \""+u+"\"")
```

These are some of the combinations i tried... but none work as intended. The Result in the Log looks like this:

```
Prozess gestartet: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "https://ecosia.org/search
```

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself and will post it for those who might be interested.

As i dug down into the sourcecode in buildmanager.cpp:

```
else if (str.at(i) == QChar('?')) {
if (str.at(++i) == QChar('?')) add = "?";
```

This means, my macro script works, when i do this:

```
%SCRIPT
u="https://ecosia.org/search??q="+cursor.selectedText()
system("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe\" \""+u+"\"")
```

Note: the "??" becomes "?" in the system call. Same for % and @

Now i can search the highlighted text directly. (i got rid of urlencode, as it behaves not as expected, due to the missing %)